# R Shiny Server will not accept UI inputs. Claims "invalid arguments"

Tags: r, input, shiny, output

I've dug through a lot of other questions on stackoverflow, and I haven't found a solution that makes things work, so I would appreciate your input.

I'm using R Shiny to take in some inputs, do some calculations, and output some results. The error is explained below.

I've reduced my application to some very simple code in order to try to isolate the problem. The simplified example below continues to return an "invalid arguments" error. It has three inputs, a simple calculation, and a histogram.

I can get it to work if I exclusively use the "input$variable" syntax in the plotting function, but that is tedious and limiting at best (especially when I need to do other calculations). I've also already written a lot of the code in regular R, and I'd rather not have to completely rewrite it.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Plot Exponentially-generated Random Numbers"),
        sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                numericInput(
                        "means",
                        "How Many Means?",
                        value = 100,
                        min = 1,
                        max = 200,
                        step = 1
                ),
                numericInput(
                        "numInMeans",
                        "Values in each mean: ",
                        value = 25,
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        step = 1
                ),
                sliderInput('lambda', 'Lambda', .01, 1, value = .2, step = .01)
        ),
        mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot")))
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
        total <- reactive({input$means*input$numInMeans})
        iLambda <- .2
        output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
                hist(rexp(n = total, rate = iLambda))
        })   
})
```

The UI part appears to work just fine.

I'm expecting a simple histogram that will change as I adjust the numeric inputs and the slider input. It should multiply the numeric inputs together, find that many exponentially distributed random values (based on the lambda value), and output a histogram plot. (Note that in the example I haven't even used the uer input lambda value.)

Comment: should be `n = total()`

Comment: Also, your `iLambda` is not calling your `sliderInput()` (i.e., the `sliderInput()` does not affect your `rate` parameter in `rexp()` at the moment).

Comment: iLambda is hard coded for the purposes of the example.